# Run-Time Error '3704' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. SQL statement in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, recordset

So I run this same exact MACRO for other reports I do but for some reason when I run this one I am getting back an error of:

> Run-Time Error 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

And when I debug it highlights this:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

From my macro which is:

```vb
Sub Bucket()

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String


strSort = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bucket").Cells(2, "A").Value

'ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
'"Data Source=RFCHaux01\sqlexpress;" & _
'"Initial Catalog=Monthly;" & _
'"Trusted_connection=yes;"

ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=RFCHaux01\sqlexpress;Database=Monthly;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cnn.CommandTimeout = 0


cnn.Open ConnectionString


'rs.ActiveConnection = cnn

StrQuery = "if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#check%') drop table #check if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#check2%') drop table #check2 if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#finaldata%') drop table #finaldata " & _
"select  i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK', " & _
        "row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', " & _
        "c.court_id, convert(char(2), month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', m.closed_yy, " & _
        "case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' " & _
"into #check from master m join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno " & _
"where (i.code in ('*WRT1DT', '*WRT2DT', '*WGRMLD', '*WgGarDT')) " & _
"select  i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', " & _
"dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK', " & _
"row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', c.court_id, " & _
"convert(char(2),month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', " & _
"m.closed_yy, case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' " & _
"into #check2 from master m join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no " & _
"join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno where (i.code in ('*WRT3DT','*WRT4DT','*BGRMLD')) " & _
"select distinct m.fileno as 'File Number', mf.sort_field as 'sort field', m.forw_no as 'Port', inside.amt_recvd, inside.trans_date, case when m.Source <> 'HISTORY\HISTORY' then 'Open' else 'Close' end as 'Status', ii4.field as 'Pooltype', " & _
"m.forw_refno as 'Unifund File Number', m.orig_claim as 'Original Amount', d.st as 'Debtor State', c.cnty_name as 'County Filed In', m.date_recd as 'Recieved Date', m.suit_date as 'Suit Date', m.jmt_date as 'Judgement Date', " & _
"m.statute_date as 'Statute of Limitation Date', Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i.field),101) as 'Suit to Court', Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i1.field),101) as 'Resent for Service', Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, ii1.field),101) as 'Served', " & _
"i2.field as 'Suit Worthiness', i3.field as 'SW Type', d.fico_score as 'Credit Score', i4.field as 'Triple Match', i5.field as 'Place Status', i6.field as 'Prior Status', case when g.code = '*WGRMLD' then 'GARN' when g.code = '*WgGarDT' then 'GARN' " & _
"when g.code = '*WRT1DT'  then 'GARN' when g.code = '*WRT2DT'  then 'GARN' else '' end as 'Garn', case when g2.code = '*BGRMLD' then 'LEVY' when g2.code = '*WRT3DT' then 'LEVY' when g2.code = '*WRT4DT' then 'LEVY'  else '' end as 'LEVY', i7.field as 'Verification Date 1', i9.field as 'Verification Of', i8.field as 'Verification Date 2', ii.field as 'Verification', m.charge_off_date, ii2.field as 'Grade', ii3.field as 'Grade D Overages', (m.int_coll + m.cost_recovered + m.prin_coll) as 'Collected' into #finaldata from master m left join(SELECT c1.fileno, c1.amt_recvd, c1.trans_date FROM colbills C1 WHERE trans_date = (SELECT MIN(trans_date) FROM colbills c2 where c1.FILENO = c2.FILENO AND c2.amt_recvd > 0 AND c2.amt_recvd IS NOT NULL)and AMT_RECVD = (select top 1 amt_recvd from colbills " & _
"where c1.fileno = fileno) and c1.AMT_RECVD > 0 group by c1.fileno, c1.AMT_RECVD, c1.TRANS_DATE) inside on inside.fileno = m.FILENO join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no join debtor d on d.fileno = m.fileno and d.number = 1 join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no left join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno and i.code = '*SCTOCT' left join infinity ii4 on ii4.fileno = m.fileno and ii4.code = '*AssetTp' left join infinity i1 on i1.fileno = m.fileno and i1.code = '*SCRSDT' left join infinity i2 on i2.fileno = m.fileno and i2.code = '*SUITREC' left join infinity i3 on i3.fileno = m.fileno and i3.code = '*SRVWFTY' left join infinity i4 on i4.fileno = m.fileno and i4.code = '*ADDMTCH' left join infinity i5 on i5.fileno = m.fileno and i5.code = '*FWCTYPE' left join infinity i6 on i6.fileno = m.fileno and i6.code = '*PRSTCOD' left join infinity i7 on i7.fileno = m.fileno and i7.code = '*PLVpD1' left join infinity i9 on i9.fileno = m.fileno and i9.code = '*PLVPN1' " & _
"left join infinity ii on ii.fileno = m.fileno and ii.code = '*PLVPN2' left join infinity i8 on i8.fileno = m.fileno and i8.code = '*PLVpD2' left join infinity ii1 on ii1.fileno = m.fileno and ii1.code = '*AMDTSV' left join infinity ii2 on ii2.fileno = m.fileno and ii2.code = '*SuitGrd' left join infinity ii3 on ii3.fileno = m.fileno and ii3.code = '*RiskGrd' left join #check g on g.fileno = m.fileno left join #check2 g2 on g2.fileno = m.fileno where (mf.sort_field = '" & strSort & "') and (m.fileno not like 'Z%' and m.fileno not like 'FOW%' ) " & _
"select f.* from #finaldata f where f.[Prior Status] <> 'RENEWED' or f.[Prior Status] is null " & _
"drop table #check drop table #check2 drop table #finaldata "

rs.Open StrQuery, cnn

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs



End Sub
```

I'm assuming that this could be because of the recordset? And maybe my query is too complex so it times out before anything happens?

I was reading somewhere that when a query is this large that I have to do a `DoEvents`, or a `For` Loop to keep the connection open till full execution but I have no idea.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of `rs.EOF` and `rs.BOF` when it fails?

Comment: I don't even get values for that, i get the same error message

Comment: @TimWilliams when i do error handling i get:  ADODB.Recordset Operation is not allowed when object is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have multiple action queries including use of temp tables. Consider build a stored procedure inside the SQL Server database and then call it from Excel with [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-a-command?view=sql-server-2017).

**SQL** *(strSort no longer concatenated but binded to @param placeholder)*

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure @param VARCHAR(50)
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#check%') 
         drop table #check 

    if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#check2%')
         drop table #check2 

    if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#finaldata%') 
         drop table #finaldata 

    select i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', 
           dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK', 
           row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', 
           c.court_id, convert(char(2), month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', m.closed_yy, 
            case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' 
    into #check 
    from master m 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno 
    where (i.code in ('*WRT1DT', '*WRT2DT', '*WGRMLD', '*WgGarDT')) 


    select  i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', 
            dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK',
            row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', c.court_id, 
            convert(char(2),month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', 
            m.closed_yy, case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' 
    into #check2 
    from master m 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno 
    where (i.code in ('*WRT3DT','*WRT4DT','*BGRMLD')) 


    select distinct m.fileno as 'File Number', mf.sort_field as 'sort field', m.forw_no as 'Port', 
                    inside.amt_recvd, inside.trans_date, 
                    case when m.Source <> 'HISTORY\HISTORY' then 'Open' else 'Close' end as 'Status',
                    ii4.field as 'Pooltype', m.forw_refno as 'Unifund File Number', m.orig_claim as 'Original Amount',
                    d.st as 'Debtor State', c.cnty_name as 'County Filed In', m.date_recd as 'Recieved Date', 
                    m.suit_date as 'Suit Date', m.jmt_date as 'Judgement Date', 
                    m.statute_date as 'Statute of Limitation Date', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i.field),101) as 'Suit to Court', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i1.field),101) as 'Resent for Service', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, ii1.field),101) as 'Served', 
                    i2.field as 'Suit Worthiness', i3.field as 'SW Type', d.fico_score as 'Credit Score', 
                    i4.field as 'Triple Match', i5.field as 'Place Status', i6.field as 'Prior Status', 
                    case when g.code = '*WGRMLD' then 'GARN'
                         when g.code = '*WgGarDT' then 'GARN' 
                         when g.code = '*WRT1DT'  then 'GARN' 
                         when g.code = '*WRT2DT'  then 'GARN'
                    else '' end as 'Garn', 
                   case when g2.code = '*BGRMLD' 
                        then 'LEVY' when g2.code = '*WRT3DT' 
                        then 'LEVY' when g2.code = '*WRT4DT' 
                        then 'LEVY'  else '' end as 'LEVY', i7.field as 'Verification Date 1', 
                   i9.field as 'Verification Of', i8.field as 'Verification Date 2', 
                   ii.field as 'Verification', m.charge_off_date, ii2.field as 'Grade', 
                   ii3.field as 'Grade D Overages', (m.int_coll + m.cost_recovered + m.prin_coll) as 'Collected' 
    into #finaldata 
    from master m 
    left join
        (SELECT c1.fileno, c1.amt_recvd, c1.trans_date 
         FROM colbills C1 
         WHERE trans_date = (SELECT MIN(trans_date) 
                             FROM colbills c2
                             where c1.FILENO = c2.FILENO 
                              AND c2.amt_recvd > 0 AND c2.amt_recvd IS NOT NULL)
           and AMT_RECVD = (select top 1 amt_recvd 
                            from colbills 
                            where c1.fileno = fileno) 
           and c1.AMT_RECVD > 0 group by c1.fileno, c1.AMT_RECVD, c1.TRANS_DATE) inside 
    on inside.fileno = m.FILENO 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join debtor d on d.fileno = m.fileno and d.number = 1 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    left join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno and i.code = '*SCTOCT' 
    left join infinity ii4 on ii4.fileno = m.fileno and ii4.code = '*AssetTp' 
    left join infinity i1 on i1.fileno = m.fileno and i1.code = '*SCRSDT' 
    left join infinity i2 on i2.fileno = m.fileno and i2.code = '*SUITREC' 
    left join infinity i3 on i3.fileno = m.fileno and i3.code = '*SRVWFTY' 
    left join infinity i4 on i4.fileno = m.fileno and i4.code = '*ADDMTCH' 
    left join infinity i5 on i5.fileno = m.fileno and i5.code = '*FWCTYPE' 
    left join infinity i6 on i6.fileno = m.fileno and i6.code = '*PRSTCOD' 
    left join infinity i7 on i7.fileno = m.fileno and i7.code = '*PLVpD1' left join infinity i9 on i9.fileno = m.fileno and i9.code = '*PLVPN1' 
    left join infinity ii on ii.fileno = m.fileno and ii.code = '*PLVPN2' 
    left join infinity i8 on i8.fileno = m.fileno and i8.code = '*PLVpD2' 
    left join infinity ii1 on ii1.fileno = m.fileno and ii1.code = '*AMDTSV' 
    left join infinity ii2 on ii2.fileno = m.fileno and ii2.code = '*SuitGrd' 
    left join infinity ii3 on ii3.fileno = m.fileno and ii3.code = '*RiskGrd' 
    left join #check g on g.fileno = m.fileno 
    left join #check2 g2 on g2.fileno = m.fileno 

    where (mf.sort_field = @param) 
      and (m.fileno not like 'Z%' and m.fileno not like 'FOW%' ) 

    select f.* from #finaldata f where f.[Prior Status] <> 'RENEWED' or f.[Prior Status] is null

    GO
  END
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String, StrSort As String, StrQuery As String

StrSort = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bucket").Cells(2, "A").Value

ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=RFCHaux01\sqlexpress;Database=Monthly;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cnn.CommandTimeout = 0

cnn.Open ConnectionString

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[myStoredProcedure]"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, StrSort)
End With

Set rs = cmd.Execute

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close: cnn.Close
Set rs = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing: Set cnn = Nothing
```

---

Comment: So this solution would be better than the previous one you posted i assume?

Comment: Also, with this, i wouldn't have to drop all the temp tables at the end?

Comment: Whatever works for you! You or future readers might not have the privilege to change the database. And performance can vary. Temp tables are dropped after session. So those were redundant lines.

Comment: one last thing... in this procedure, how do i declare the @-param?  i tried putting that in the stored procedure as Declare @-param VarChar(50); but the vba gave me back the error saying myStoredProcedure has no parameters

Comment: Do not declare parameter. Pass `@param` outside on the `CREATE PROCEDURE` line. See edit.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help. How about the `CTE` version?

Comment: they both work great. Im choosing this one so that its always in the database, and not a sql file that can be deleted by accident.  Also, it seems like the stored procedure runs faster than the .sql file.  I read somewhere that this is one of the reasons to use a sp because its faster (i think from cache from previous times being run?)

Comment: Perfect answer! It's often advised to run long processes in stored procs as you mention for security and efficiency of your business logic. And the database does save statistics of its objects.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing the use of temp tables for [WITH CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statements for **one** output resultset.

**SQL** *(save as long, formatted .sql text file to read in VBA)*

```sql
WITH [check] AS (
    select i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', 
           dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK', 
           row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', 
           c.court_id, convert(char(2), month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', m.closed_yy, 
            case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' 
    from master m 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno 
    where (i.code in ('*WRT1DT', '*WRT2DT', '*WGRMLD', '*WgGarDT')) 
),

WITH [check2] AS (    
    select  i.fileno, i.code, substring(i.field,0,5) + substring(i.field,6,2) as 'FILED_MONTH', 
            dense_rank() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.field desc) as 'GARN_GOAL_CHECK',
            row_number() over(partition by i.fileno order by i.date desc, i.code desc) as 'row_check', c.court_id, 
            convert(char(2),month(m.date_recd),100) + '/' + convert(char(4),year(m.date_recd),100)  as 'MONTH_RECD', 
            m.closed_yy, case when m.jmt_amt is null then m.suit_amt else m.jmt_amt end as 'PLACED_AMT' 
    from master m 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno 
    where (i.code in ('*WRT3DT','*WRT4DT','*BGRMLD')) 
),

WITH finaldata AS (    
    select distinct m.fileno as 'File Number', mf.sort_field as 'sort field', m.forw_no as 'Port', 
                    inside.amt_recvd, inside.trans_date, 
                    case when m.Source <> 'HISTORY\HISTORY' then 'Open' else 'Close' end as 'Status',
                    ii4.field as 'Pooltype', m.forw_refno as 'Unifund File Number', m.orig_claim as 'Original Amount',
                    d.st as 'Debtor State', c.cnty_name as 'County Filed In', m.date_recd as 'Recieved Date', 
                    m.suit_date as 'Suit Date', m.jmt_date as 'Judgement Date', 
                    m.statute_date as 'Statute of Limitation Date', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i.field),101) as 'Suit to Court', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, i1.field),101) as 'Resent for Service', 
                    Convert(VARCHAR(50),Convert(Datetime, ii1.field),101) as 'Served', 
                    i2.field as 'Suit Worthiness', i3.field as 'SW Type', d.fico_score as 'Credit Score', 
                    i4.field as 'Triple Match', i5.field as 'Place Status', i6.field as 'Prior Status', 
                    case when g.code = '*WGRMLD' then 'GARN'
                         when g.code = '*WgGarDT' then 'GARN' 
                         when g.code = '*WRT1DT'  then 'GARN' 
                         when g.code = '*WRT2DT'  then 'GARN'
                    else '' end as 'Garn', 
                    case when g2.code = '*BGRMLD' then 'LEVY' 
                         when g2.code = '*WRT3DT' then 'LEVY'
                         when g2.code = '*WRT4DT' 
                         then 'LEVY'  else '' end as 'LEVY', i7.field as 'Verification Date 1', 
                   i9.field as 'Verification Of', i8.field as 'Verification Date 2', 
                   ii.field as 'Verification', m.charge_off_date, ii2.field as 'Grade', 
                   ii3.field as 'Grade D Overages', (m.int_coll + m.cost_recovered + m.prin_coll) as 'Collected'  
    from master m 
    left join
        (SELECT c1.fileno, c1.amt_recvd, c1.trans_date 
         FROM colbills C1 
         WHERE trans_date = (SELECT MIN(trans_date) 
                             FROM colbills c2
                             where c1.FILENO = c2.FILENO 
                              AND c2.amt_recvd > 0 AND c2.amt_recvd IS NOT NULL)
           and AMT_RECVD = (select top 1 amt_recvd 
                            from colbills 
                            where c1.fileno = fileno) 
           and c1.AMT_RECVD > 0 group by c1.fileno, c1.AMT_RECVD, c1.TRANS_DATE) inside 
    on inside.fileno = m.FILENO 
    join masforw mf on mf.forw_no = m.forw_no 
    join debtor d on d.fileno = m.fileno and d.number = 1 
    join clerkf c on c.venue_no = m.venue1_no 
    left join infinity i on i.fileno = m.fileno and i.code = '*SCTOCT' 
    left join infinity ii4 on ii4.fileno = m.fileno and ii4.code = '*AssetTp' 
    left join infinity i1 on i1.fileno = m.fileno and i1.code = '*SCRSDT' 
    left join infinity i2 on i2.fileno = m.fileno and i2.code = '*SUITREC' 
    left join infinity i3 on i3.fileno = m.fileno and i3.code = '*SRVWFTY' 
    left join infinity i4 on i4.fileno = m.fileno and i4.code = '*ADDMTCH' 
    left join infinity i5 on i5.fileno = m.fileno and i5.code = '*FWCTYPE' 
    left join infinity i6 on i6.fileno = m.fileno and i6.code = '*PRSTCOD' 
    left join infinity i7 on i7.fileno = m.fileno and i7.code = '*PLVpD1' 
    left join infinity i9 on i9.fileno = m.fileno and i9.code = '*PLVPN1' 
    left join infinity ii on ii.fileno = m.fileno and ii.code = '*PLVPN2' 
    left join infinity i8 on i8.fileno = m.fileno and i8.code = '*PLVpD2' 
    left join infinity ii1 on ii1.fileno = m.fileno and ii1.code = '*AMDTSV' 
    left join infinity ii2 on ii2.fileno = m.fileno and ii2.code = '*SuitGrd' 
    left join infinity ii3 on ii3.fileno = m.fileno and ii3.code = '*RiskGrd' 
    left join [check] g on g.fileno = m.fileno 
    left join [check2] g2 on g2.fileno = m.fileno 

    where (mf.sort_field = ?) 
      and (m.fileno not like 'Z%' and m.fileno not like 'FOW%' ) 
)

select f.* from finaldata f 
where f.[Prior Status] <> 'RENEWED' 
   or f.[Prior Status] is null
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String, StrSort As String, StrQuery As String
Dim i As Integer

' READ SQL QUERY FROM FILE
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      StrQuery = .OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\mySQLQuery.sql", 1).readall
End With

' OPEN DB CONNECTION
ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=RFCHaux01\sqlexpress;Database=Monthly;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cnn.CommandTimeout = 0

cnn.Open ConnectionString

' DEFINE COMMAND OBJECT
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = StrQuery
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, StrSort)
End With

' BIND OUTPUT TO RECORDSET
Set rs = cmd.Execute

' COPY TO WORKSHEET
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' COLUMNS
    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
       .Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i 
    ' DATA
   .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close: cnn.Close
Set rs = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing: Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: I also tried it with this and i get back an error when i run the macro of:  Must Declare the scalar variable "@ param"

Comment: Replace the "@param" in the SQL query with `?` (unquoted qmark). See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` anywhere in the SQL query command.  This fixed it for me.

-- [Run-time error ‘3704’ Operation is not allowed when the object is closed](https://dacosta9.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/run-time-error-3704-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed/)

Comment: "SET NOCOUNT ON;" may be not sufficient. This is the case where there are some warning coming from the query/stored procedure. In order to be sure to have no issues raised by VBA/.NET (like "Run-time error ‘3704’") you have also to add "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF"